# Replace the second-to-last occurrence of string in each line

Tags: text-processing

I have an example output file with the following contents:

```
ent_status_code,time_stamp) using btree  in table ;

user_id,ent_no) using btree  in table ;

agent_code,ent_no) using btree  in table ;

ent_no,change_ind_code) using btree  in table ;

change_ind_code) using btree  in table ;

using btree  in table ;

using btree  in table ;

ent_no) using btree  in table ;

ent_status_code,time_stamp) using btree  in table ;

user_id,ent_no) using btree  in table ;

agent_code,ent_no) using btree  in table ;

ent_no,change_ind_code) using btree  in table ;

change_ind_code) using btree  in table ;

using btree  in table ;

using btree  in table ;

ent_no) using btree  in table ;

using btree  in table ;

using btree  in table ;

ent_no) using btree  in table ;
```

My aim is to replace the second-to-last column, which in this case is ***`table`***; however, that column is not unique so it does not have to be ***`table`***. I would like to replace this with ***`datadbs`***

Comment: Are the blank lines part of your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special `NF` variable in `awk` holds the number of space-delineated fields in the current line. Therefore, `$(NF-1)` will be the penultimate field, so you can just do:

```
awk 'NF>1 && $(NF-1) = "datadbs"' file
```